# "confusing for tourists" vs "confusing to the user"

Tags: prepositions, difference

> (1) The new signs will be very confusing **for** tourists.
>
> (2) All this information can be confusing **to** the user.
>
> ([source](https://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=confusing))

**Question:** Could you please explain to me why (1) uses **for** while (2) uses **to**?

Comment: The two prepositions could be swapped there with little practical change of meaning. I would say that the sentence with **for** refers to how the signs present information, and the sentence with **to** refers to the limitations of users. The complement of **for** can be the intended audience, and the complement of **to** can be those affected by something.  "Some plants are poisonous to cats".  "Some herbal supplements are beneficial for people with arthritis."

Comment: (1) A confusing situation for tourists to cope with. (2) A source of confusion to the user. As Tim says, very little actual difference in meaning.

Comment: There's not much difference in meaning, but "**to** **to**urists" is a bit more awkward to _say_, which is probably why your examples use them that way.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be to use **to**, but you can use either **to** or **for**. They are essentially interchangeable.

> The new signs will be very confusing for tourists.
>
> The new signs will be very confusing to tourists.

> All this information can be confusing to the user.
>
> All this information can be confusing for the user.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the two are interchangeable. You could say, "The signs will be confusing to tourists" or "This information can be confusing for the user". "Confusing to" and "Confusing for" mean the same thing.